# How to addclass next element with on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need `addclass('active')` next `thm-img` element when I click `sl-rgh`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var Thumbnail = $('.thm-img'); // main image wrapper
  var ThumbnailActive = $('.thm-img.active'); // main image wrapper active
  var Numeric = $('.numeric'); //slider number
  var NumericActive = $('.numeric.active'); //slider number
  var AllNumber = $(Thumbnail).length; // Thumbnail counter
  var SlideNext = $('.sl-rgh'); //right arrow
  var ThumbnailsContainer = $('.thumb-wrp');

  // Thumbnails counter
  function ThumbnailCounter() {

    Thumbnail.each(function() {
      var CurrentActive = $(this).index() + 1; //return current number active thumbnail
      $(this).children('span').append(CurrentActive + '/' + AllNumber);
    });
    Thumbnail.mouseenter(function() {
      //active
      Thumbnail.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      //numeric
      Numeric.removeClass('active');
      $(this).children(Numeric).addClass('active')
    });
  }

  new ThumbnailCounter();

  // slide right
  function SlideRight() {
    SlideNext.on('click', function() {
      ThumbnailsContainer.animate({
        'scrollTop': '+=115px'
      }, 100);
      Thumbnail.find(NumericActive).parent(Thumbnail).next().addClass('active');
    });

  }

  new SlideRight();


});
```

```css
.det-sl-wrp {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 480px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mn-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 641px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #BAC0C6;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mn-img a {
  opacity: 1;
}
.mn-img .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: 40px;
}
.mn-img .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: 40px;
}
.thumb-wrp {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 153px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
}
.thumb-wrp li {
  float: none !important;
}
.thumb-wrp .flex-viewport {
  height: 100% !important;
}
#detail-slider .flex-viewport {
  height: 100% !important;
}
.mn-img img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mn-img iframe {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sl-lft,
.sl-rgh {
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.sl-lft::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 7px;
  top: 200px;
  background: rgba(132, 143, 153, 0.9) url("../img/icons/left-arrow.svg") no-repeat center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: 25px;
}
.sl-rgh::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  right: 7px;
  top: 200px;
  background: rgba(132, 143, 153, 0.9) url("../img/icons/right-arrow.svg") no-repeat center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: 25px;
}
.sl-rgh {
  left: inherit;
  right: 226px;
  /*    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=1);*/
}
.sl-rgh:hover,
.sl-lft:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sl-rgh-off,
.sl-lft-off {
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.sl-rgh-off {
  left: inherit;
  right: 154px;
}
.thm-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: border 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}
.thm-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.numeric {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 0 1px 0;
  line-height: 11px;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 11;
  background-color: #E78211;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.numeric.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.active-thumb,
.active-thumb span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="det-sl-wrp">

  <div class="sl-rgh-off"></div>
  <!-- disable right arrow when slider ends -->
  <div class="sl-lft-off"></div>
  <!-- disable left arrow when slider ends -->

  <div class="sl-rgh"></div>
  <div class="sl-lft"></div>
  <div class="mn-img">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/a.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/b.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/c.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/d.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/a.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/c.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/b.jpg">
    <img class="full-img" src="../img/img/d.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="thumb-wrp scrollbar-inner">
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/a.jpg"><span class="numeric active"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/b.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/c.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/d.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/a.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/c.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/b.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="thm-img">
      <img src="../img/img/d.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it will be something like this, i haven't used jQuery for maybe 2 years now, so test it out before usage it's all out of my memory:

```
$('.sl-rgh').on('click', function(){
  var add_active_to_next = false;
  $('.thm-img').map(function(e){
     if($(e).hasClass('active')){
      add_active_to_next = true;
      $(e).removeClass(); 
     }
     if(add_active_to_next === true){
       add_active_to_next = false;
       $(e).addClass('active');
     }

  });

});
```